# Derivative: $f_x, f_y, f_{xy}$ of function - $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let's say $f(x,y) = x^2 + 2xy +y^2$

$f'_x = 2x + 2y$

$f'_y = 2y + 2x$

$f'_{xy} = 2x + 2y$ ?

Am I right about the third?

Comment: No, the third is the derivative of the second with respect to x or the first with respect to y, you get the same thing, 2.

Comment: I want to point out that in principle $f_{xy}=(f_x)_y$, but in this particular case [Schwarz's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem) applies and so the comment above is true.

Comment: +1 to @GitGud's comment, although some conventions have $f_{xy}=(f_y)_x$ so that written order is preserved with $f_{xy}=\partial_x\partial_yf$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f_x = 2x + 2y$$

$$f_y = 2y + 2x$$

$$f_{xy} = \frac{\partial{f_x}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{\partial{(2x + 2y)}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{\partial{(2x)}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{(2y)}}{\partial{y}}=2\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{y}}+2\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{y}}\overset{(*)}{=} 2 \cdot 0+2 \cdot 1=2$$

$(*)$ When we differentiate $x$ with respect to $y$, $x$ is like a constant, so $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{y}}=0}$.

$$\text{ OR }$$

$$f_{xy} = \frac{\partial{f_y}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{(2y + 2x)}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{(2y)}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{(2x)}}{\partial{x}}=2\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}+2\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x}}\overset{(**)}{=} 2 \cdot 1+2 \cdot 0=2$$

$(**)$ When we differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$, $y$ is like a constant, so $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}=0}$.

Comment: why it's not (2+2)/1 which is 4?

Comment: @momd When you're differentiate with respect to $y$ you're treating $x$ as a constant. And the opposite is true.

Comment: why you wrote 0+2? the diff' of 2x is 2 and the diff of x is 1. then it's 2/1, no?

Comment: The partial derivative of 2x with respect to x is 2, but the partial derivative of 2x with respect to y is zero.